# Sort a .NET Dictionary - bug or unsupported feature?

Tags: .net, sorting, dictionary

I recently found productive code including the sorting of a .NET `Dictionary<string,CustomObject>`. It was basically to copy the dictionary to a temporary one, then .Clear() the original and insert the KeyValuePairs ordered through a Linq expression, by a DateTime value in the CustomObjects.

I expected this code not to work and was already removing it, expecting that a dictionary (as well as a HashSet) can't be sorted. Then I wrote the following test code, which, to my surprise, showed a sorted output from the dictionary, when iterated with a foreach loop.

Is this a random effect in the current implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which may work in the current case, but fail in another implementation of .NET? Or is it a standard feature to be used in .NET Dictionaries?

I still consider the productive code to be faulty, but working. Should I remove it, requiring a long testing, if the order is used somewhere else than in the place where I found the sorting routine, or is it safe to leave it as it is?

Here's my test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        int rndValue;
        do
        {
            rndValue = rnd.Next(100);
        }
        while (dict.ContainsKey(rndValue));

        dict.Add(rndValue, "MyValue#" + i);
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + ", Value: " + pair.Value);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    var dictBuff = dict.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    dict.Clear();

    var sortdict = from pair in dictBuff orderby pair.Key ascending select pair;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in sortdict)
    {
        dict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("'Sorted' Dictionary:");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + ", Value: " + pair.Value);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter...");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's based on the current implementation, but isn't guaranteed across implementations. The order is not guaranteed unless you use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx), or if you change your last foreach loop to iterate over dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key).

[From the documentation (Remarks section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. ***The order in which the items are returned is undefined.***

Comment: The behavior he's seeing is not a random effect. It is a side effect of the current internal implementation of Dictionary. You really will get the items back in the order they're put in. It shouldn't be counted on because the implementation of Dictionary may change.

Comment: @hatchet: True. Updated for clarity.

Comment: @hatchet: I wish MS would specify that a `Dictionary` from which no items have *ever* been removed will return all items in the order they were added.  Making any guarantee about if or when slots which are vacated due to deletion will get recycled will increase the cost of a dictionary, but dictionaries from which things are never deleted form a common usage case, and it would cost nothing to offer stronger guarantees in that usage case than in others (much how non-generic HashTable can cheaply guarantee single-writer multi-reader thread-safety if no items are ever deleted)

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary is simply a list with an identifier for each element, so the elements will be returned in the order they have been put in. However, there is no guarantee no one for example removes an element only to insert it again, which would put it at the back again.

I would recommend you use the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f7fta44c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class if you want to ensure that the Dictionary stays sorted.

Or you do let LINQ sort the dictionary whenever you need it ordered.

By the way, you can replace this code part:

```
    var sortdict = from pair in dictBuff orderby pair.Key ascending select pair;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in sortdict)
    {
        dict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
```

with

```
    foreach (var pair in dictBuff.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
    {
        //dict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        //meaningful code here
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You could do one other thing instead of using SortedDictionary: use a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` or Array instead of `Dictionary<int, string>`. The usage when iterating is exactly the same, you will not be able to use the indexer like `list[someItem]` though. You would then need to do `list.Single(x => x.Key == someItem)` or alternatively use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

```
//var sortedList = dictBuff.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToArray();
var sortedList = dictBuff.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: "The Dictionary is simply a list with an identifier for each element, so the elements will be returned in the order they have been put in." - this is wrong, enumerating over a .NET Dictionary does not necessarily return items in the order they were inserted.

Comment: Internally it works like a list. However it is not a guaranteed behaviour.